# creating a view without join in SQL

Tags: sql, join, view

I have two tables:

**Customers**
`customer_id`,
`name`

**Orders**
`customer_id`,
`date`,
`amount`

I want to create a view with: `customer_id`, `name`, `is_active` - a boolean field that holds the value `true` when the customer has at least one record in the **Orders** table for the current year.

Can I do it without using the `join` operator?

Comment: Question is somewhat vague. Why would you want to do that? Have you considered using subqueries and case when clauses?

Comment: Please, describe why you want to avoid `join`, because the real requirement is not clear. And you obviously cannot know if something exists or not until you check it, regardless of what is the name of that operation (join/subquery/function/etc). Do we need to play with terminology?

Answer (score 0):

You can, and probably should, use `exists`.

Different platforms have varying syntax for date functions eg `current_date / getdate() / currdate()` etc - use whichever is correct for your RDBMS.

```
select c.Customer_Id, c.Name,
  case when exists (
    select * 
    from Orders o 
    where o.Customer_Id = c.customer_Id and year(o.date) = year(current_date)) 
  then 1 else 0 end as Is_Active
from Customers c;
```